# python - Dict of Dict of List using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to group a pandas DataFrame as below. A Dictionary with stocks, and each stock has its own dictionary to capture date & timestamp. And each of those entries will have the OHLC values for that period. Since this is run in Live market, the date and timestamp needs to be a dictionary to reupdate the values. As the initial DataFrame has around 100,000 entries, creating the Dict of Dict of List manually takes over 30 seconds.

```
Stock(Dict)     Day(Dict)               Open, High, Low, Close(List)    
A1              2023-01-01 09:15:00     100, 102, 99, 101
                2023-01-02 09:15:20     100, 102, 99, 101
B1              2023-01-01 09:15:00     100, 102, 99, 101
                2023-01-02 09:20:00     100, 102, 99, 101
```

I am able to create the Dict of Dicts but only populate one value from Open, High, Low, Close

```
g = df_symbols_all.set_index('day').groupby('symbol').apply(lambda x: x.high.to_dict()).to_dict()
```

[image]

If I try to pass all values, it does not create the date & timestamp dictionary.

```
k= df_symbols_all.set_index('day').groupby('symbol').apply(lambda x: (x.open.to_dict(), x.high.to_dict(), x.low.to_dict(), x.close.to_dict())).to_dict()
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new column that combines the ('open', 'close','high','low') into a single column (this can be performed fast):

```
df_symbols_all['open_high_low_close'] = df_symbols_all[['open','close','high','low']].values.tolist()
```

and then perform the grouping as you suggested

```
g = df_symbols_all.set_index('day').groupby('symbol').apply(lambda x: x.open_high_low_close.to_dict()).to_dict()
```